# clearing the cache in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Currently, I am facing a strange issue in my Angular 2 application.

I have two component for addition of records and update record i.e. menu-add and menu-edit.

And these components are injected in main module also.

Everything is working fine but I have changed some code in menu-add.ts and clean/build/rebuild vs project too, but I am not getting the changes reflection in website, even in console I am getting old code.

So is their any way to versioning components in module.ts or versioning whole angular app?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clear browser cache in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55517060/clear-browser-cache-in-angular)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Chrome browser:

- open developer tools (F12)
- open tab Network
- check 'Disable cache'
- use CTRL+F5 to refresh

You can also check the compiled output Javascript files in the dist folder (or other output path).

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem with Angular. There are two methods for this:

- Refresh by pressing Ctrl + F5 to clear the cache
- It may not work if you use template files linked to `templateUrl` attribute. In this case, the only solution is to clear the cache of your browser.

Comment: actually I maintain cache clear with Ctrl + F5 but today it was not working as usual.

Comment: In a working application, how can we tell our users to clear caches. This certainly is not the right approach.